# How to create a WPF ListBoxItem with check mark?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, microsoft-metro, listboxitem

I was looking a while for how to build a list item with a check mark if selected.

Checking different Resources, it seems there are a lot of code solutions, bot no true XAML only one.

So this is what i tried to achive:

[image: Selection]

Any additions are welcomed.

*In the spirit of [Answer-your-own (Stackoverflow blog)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I actually got after hours of figuring it out.
As said, any additions are welcomed.

[image: Selection]

**The check mark is:**

```
U+2714 (10004)  ✔   HEAVY CHECK MARK    Dingbats (2700–27BF)
```

**The style code:**

- basically creating a wrapper for any item, setting base properties, and changing them on item selection, made available as `StaticResource` as `checkmarkItem`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="checkmarkItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border Name="Border" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="0,1,0,1">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="Marker" Visibility="Hidden" Background="#0078D7" Padding="5,0,0,5" Foreground="White">✔</TextBlock>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ListBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Marker" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#0078D7"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**The implementation:**

- it is just a regular stackpanel arrangement, all styles are added by referring in `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource checkmarkItem}"`

```
<Grid>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" FontSize="26">Software</Label>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Multiple" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource checkmarkItem}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="64" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Height="48" Width="48" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,20,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
</Grid>
```